SoapCore is unable to deserializing the soap request which contains href references
We have a legacy soap envelop like below which references a product xml using href as shown below.
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://webservices.google.net/abc.NET" xmlns:types="http://webservices.google.net/abc.NET/encodedTypes" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <tns:Tally>
            <SerialNumber>123456</SerialNumber>
            <Product href="#id1" />
        </tns:Tally>
        <tns:Product id="id1">
            <Name>Noodles</Name>
            <Type>Food</Type>
        </tns:Product>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

We have a service contract like below. We want to be able to deserialize above soaprequest into following webmethod.
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://webservices.google.net/abc.NET")]
public interface IProductTallier
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "Tally_Test")]
    Task<CorrectedAddress> Tally(string SerialNumber, Product product);
}

Currently, we are facing two problems with soap core.

We are getting following soap error because soapcore is expecting Tally_Test envelop to be sent instead of Tally when calling SoapAction Tally_Test. How do we resolve this?


<soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Start element 'Tally_Test' from namespace 'http://webservices.google.net/abc.NET' expected. Found element 'tns:Tally' from namespace 'http://webservices.google.net/abc.NET'.</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>



If we modify the above soap envelop with Tally_Test instead of Tally, the webmethod is getting called without any soap fault. However, the product is not deserialized correctly and its empty. Is there any way we can deserialize above soap envelop correctly?

